# Python not interpreted on apache

Tags: python, apache

I'm trying to set up Python to run on my local apache server on a mac.

On `httpd.conf`, I've

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/ptamzz/Sites/python/sandbox.ptamzz.com"
    <Directory "/Users/pritams/Sites/python/sandbox.ptamzz.com">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI
        AddHandler cgi-script .py
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    DirectoryIndex index.py
    ServerName sandbox.ptamzz.com
    ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/error-log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/access-log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

On my document root, I've my `index.py` file as

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "Content-type: text/html"
print "<html><body>Pritam's Page</body></html>"
```

But when I load the page on my browser, the python codes are returned as it is.
[image: Screenshot]

What all am I missing?

Comment: have you set execute permission with chmod ?

Comment: Yes. I've set it to 755

Comment: uncommented LoadModule cgi_module libexec/apache2/mod_cgi.so  ?

Comment: Just uncommented it. Now something is happening. Throws an internal server error instead! I don't see any error on the error log though! :/

Comment: sudo apachectl -t check for errors

Comment: Thanks for helping. Still couldn't figure out though. `sudo apachectl -t` returns Syntax OK but I still got 500 Internal Server Error in the browser.

Comment: i have added complete steps by which i got it working on my machine . check it and see if you are missing something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Executing python in Apache ( cgi )**

System : OSX yosmite 10.10.3 , Default apache

**uncommented in http config**

```
LoadModule cgi_module libexec/apache2/mod_cgi.so
```

**virtual hosts entry**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    # Hook virtual host domain name into physical location.
    ServerName python.localhost
    DocumentRoot "/Users/sj/Sites/python"

    # Log errors to a custom log file.
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/pythonlocal.log"

    # Add python file extensions as CGI script handlers.
    AddHandler cgi-script .py

    # Be sure to add ** ExecCGI ** as an option in the document
    # directory so Apache has permissions to run CGI scripts.

    <Directory "/Users/sj/Sites/python">

    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all


    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

**index.py file**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
print "Content-type: text/html" 
print 
print "<html><body>Test Page</body></html>"
```

file was made executable using

```
chmod a+x index.py
```

**restarted apache and output**

[image: python in apache]

Comment: Thanks, finally it works! I `chmod index.py` as you mentioned here, and modified the two `AddHandler` lines.
What's the difference if I put `AddHandler cgi-script .py` inside `<directory>` vs outside?

Comment: @ptamzz actually i didn't do it knowingly :P . Actually its not supposed to make a difference . I think the chmod part was your problem .

Answer (score 0):

For later Versions of Apache (2.4) the answer of Sojan V Jose is mostly still applying, except that I got an authorization failure, that can be resolved by replacing:

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

with:

```
Require all granted
```