# Python index page on apache2

Tags: python, apache, ubuntu, cgi

I want to serve `index.py` as the index page using apache2 on Ubuntu 21.04.

I have this Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu/apache2:2.4-21.04_beta

RUN rm -rf /var/www/html/*
ADD html /var/www/html
RUN chmod +x /var/www/html/*py
ADD virtual-hosts.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

The `html` directory contains `index.py`. The `RUN chmod` line has no effect (!) but if I `chmod` manually when the container is running, that doesn't fix the problem.

`virtual-hosts.conf` is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29723590/python-not-interpreted-on-apache) (which is OSX, if that matters)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName pilights

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    AddHandler cgi-script .py

    <Directory "/var/www/html">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
        AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The above linked answer also says I need to uncomment `LoadModule cgi_module libexec/apache2/mod_cgi.so` in "http config", which I interpret to mean `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, but that file does not contain a line like that to uncomment, and adding it does nothing.

The above setup does not work. I browse to `http://localhost` and get a directory index which shows `index.py` but does not execute the script.

Comment: Same case here. Have you found any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the below are set correctly. `sudo su` if you are not root user

- use python3 as default

```bash
python --version

# run only if the result saying the version is not python 3 
rm -rf /usr/bin/python

# create a symlink
ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python

# test
python --version

apt-get update
apt-get install python3-pip
```

- miscellaneous settings

```bash
# disable multi-threading processes
a2dismod mpm_event

# give apache explicit permission to run python scripts
a2enmod mpm_prefork cpi
```

- apply the same in your site conf

```
<Directory your-absolute-site-directory-of-which-index.py-can-be-found>
    Options +ExecCGI
    DirectoryIndex index.py
    Require all granted
    # Allow local .htaccess to override Apache configuration settings
    AllowOverride all
</Directory>

AddHandler cgi-script .py
```

- then run

```bash
service apache2 restart
```

- add `#!/usr/bin/python` to `index.py`
- navigate to your site. If problem still exists, touch `.htaccess` and `nano` it with the below content:

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .py
DirectoryIndex index.py
```

- navigate again the site and you are good to go

For more detailed explanation, you can head to [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-apache-mysql-and-python-lamp-server-without-frameworks-on-ubuntu-14-04).